# How to tell a viewcontroller to update its UI from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to understand how updating of a `viewController` that is currently visible works.
I have `ViewControllerA` and `ClassA`. I want to tell `ViewControllerA` to reloadData on the `tableview` from `ClassA`. What is the best way to go about doing this?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604872/ios-updating-viewcontroller-uilabel-from-another-class) question and answer but I dont think this will work in my situation or I am not understanding it correctly.

Comment: what is your classA inherited from??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way without knowing your setup would be to use `NSNotificationCenter`. Here is what you could do:

In `ViewControllerA` add in hooks for `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Register for notification setting the observer to your table and the UITableViewMethod reloadData. So when this NSNotification is received, it tells your UITableView to reloadData
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.table selector:@selector(reloadData) name:@"ViewControllerAReloadData" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //Need to remove the listener so it doesn't get notifications when the view isn't visible or unloaded.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Then in `ClassA` when you want to tell ViewControllerA to reload data just post the `NSNotification`.

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewControllerAReloadData" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, Thank you for such a simple informative answer!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could help. Just make sure to accept it when you can.

Answer (score 2):

Answers here about using NSNotificationCenter are good.  Be aware of a few other approaches:

A common one is the delegate pattern ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)).

Another is that the view controller observes the model change using KVO.  (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148833/iphone-kvo-between-two-classes)).

Another good one, often overlooked, which can probably be used in your case is the "do almost nothing" pattern.  Just reloadData on your table view when viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

Key value Coding , NSNotificationCentre and Delegates are preferred. But NSNotificationCentre is easiest in your case.

The UIViewController that contains UITableView must add observer like this :
Init :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(methodToReloadTable:) 
    name:@"TABLE_RELOAD"
    object:nil];
```

In delloc method :

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Post it from any XYZ class like on any UIButton action :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TABLE_RELOAD" 
        object:self];
```

Advantage of NSNotificationCentre is that they can add observers in multiple classes ..